# Using CSS3 Animations one each slide within a jQuery slideshow (FF issues)

Tags: jquery, firefox, slideshow, css-animations

Here is my problem:

I have a jQuery slideshow (using the .cycle lite plugin), and basically I have a super simple fade transition between each slide. Easy enough.

Each main element inside the slides have CSS3-animations applied to them so that when they enter the scene it's a bit more animated than a simple slide.

It works perfectly in webkit, but firefox only applies the css3 animation to the first slide. The rest of the slides just simply fade in.

I was wondering if anyone knows why this is, and if there is a fix, or if my code is messed up.

Thanks!

HTML

```
<div class="slideshow">
    <div class="slide" id="slide_01">
        <div class="sec_01></div>
        <div class="sec_02></div>
        <div class="sec_03></div>
    </div>
    <div class="slide" id="slide_02">
        <div class="sec_01></div>
        <div class="sec_02></div>
        <div class="sec_03></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
/* ANIMATIONS */

Move In from left
@-moz-keyframes fadeLeft {
  0% {-moz-transform:translate(5000px,0);}
  70% {-moz-transform:translate(-100px,0);}
  100% {-moz-transform:translate(0,0);}
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeLeft {
  0% {-webkit-transform:translate(5000px,0);}
  70% {-webkit-transform:translate(-100px,0);}
  100% {-webkit-transform:translate(0,0);}
}

---------------------------

Move in from right

@-moz-keyframes fadeRight {
  0% {-moz-transform:translate(-5000px,0);}
  70% {-moz-transform:translate(100px,0);}
  100% {-moz-transform:translate(0,0);}
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeRight {
  0% {-webkit-transform:translate(-5000px,0);}
  70% {-webkit-transform:translate(100px,0);}
  100% {-webkit-transform:translate(0,0);}
}

----------------------

Move in from Top
@-moz-keyframes fadeTop {
  0% {-moz-transform:translate(0,-800px);}
  70% {-moz-transform:translate(0,100px);}
  100% {-moz-transform:translate(0,0);}
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeTop {
  0% {-webkit-transform:translate(0,-800px);}
  70% {-webkit-transform:translate(0,100px);}
  100% {-webkit-transform:translate(0,0);}
}



CSS applied to each slide

/* SEC_01 */
.slide .sec_01 {-webkit-animation:fadeRight .5s ease;  -moz-animation:fadeRight .5s ease;}

/* SEC_02 */
.slide .sec_02 {-webkit-animation:fadeTop .5s ease;  -moz-animation:fadeTop .5s ease;}


/* SEC_02 */
.slide .sec_03 {-webkit-animation:fadeLeft .75s ease;  -moz-animation:fadeLeft .75s ease; }
```

So basically I want the same animation effects to be applied to each section of the individual slides, which is why I don't use any IDs for the styling.

Any help you can give will be much appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: The animation CSS is applied to all the slides at once?  Doesn't that mean the animations all start at once, and so when the first one finishes they're all done?

Comment: This is one of my thoughts... But on webkit it works just the way I want it to, so either webkit is running it wrong, or perhaps there's something I need to change in my code. Just not quite sure yet.

Comment: It's really hard to say what's going on with WebKit without a complete testcase....

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your naming in your CSS: .sec_01 for example and in your code you set the class section_1 not sec_01.

is it correct?

Comment: Good call. Fixed that in my original post. It is correct in my html though.